# django prefetch_related id only

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to optimise my queries but prefetch_related insists on joining the tables and selecting all the fields even though I only need the list of ids from the relations table.

[image: queries]

You can ignore the 4th query. It's not related to the question.

Related Code:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    ...
    Groups = models.ManyToManyField(ContactGroup, related_name='contacts')
    ...

queryset = Contact.objects.all().prefetch_related('Groups')
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Django 1.7 added [`Prefetch` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#new-prefetch-object-for-advanced-prefetch-related-operations) which let you customise the queryset used when prefetching.

In particular, see [`only()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#only).

In this case, you'd want something like:

```
queryset = Contact.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('Groups', queryset=Group.objects.all().only('id')))
```

Comment: In Django 1.11 with Postgres, I needed to additionally select the foreign key of the prefetched object -- otherwise Django was doing a DB lookup for each prefetched object to select the foreign key (which is worse than no prefetch at all). In this example, the modification would be: `queryset=Group.objects.all().only('id', 'contact_id'))`

Comment: @erikreed thanks, i came here for this confirmation !

Comment: @erikeed I'm using Django 3.1 and i don't need to select the foreign key. As a matter of fact, including the foreign key approximately doubles the time taken for the query to be evaluated (depending on your table structure of course :) )

Comment: For those looking for the respective import: `from django.db.models import Prefetch`

Comment: @ImportError on Django `3.2.14` and needs the foreign key otherwise its not a single query. Tested via `self.assertNumQueries`